# How does the in keyword of for loop in dictionary comprehensions work?

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have the following code snippet:

```
d = {1:2, 3:4, 5:6}
d1 = {k*2:v/2 for (k,v) in d.items()}
d2 = {k*2:v/2 for [k,v] in d.items()}
d3 = {k*2:v/2 for [k,v] in d.items() if [k,v] in d.items()}
print(d1)
print(d2)
print(d3)
```

this produces the following output:

```
{2: 1.0, 6: 2.0, 10: 3.0}
{2: 1.0, 6: 2.0, 10: 3.0}
{}
```

Dictionary comprehension of `d1` makes sense as it checks for a tuple of form `(k,v)` in `d.items()` which is "kind of" list of tuples.

Dictionary comprehension of `d2` should return `{}` as the list `[k,v]` isn't present in `d.items()` which is verified in dictionary comprehension of `d3`.

What is the difference between the `in` inside the `for` loop and using it outside?

Comment: The `in` keyword as part of the `for ... in ...` construct is completely unrelated to its use as an operator. They simply happen to share the same keyword. That is all.

Comment: `for (k,v) in d.items()` works the same way in comprehensions as it does in for loops, and `if [k,v] in d.items()` works the same way in comprehensions that it does in a separate `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [for statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) docs, `for target_list in expression_list` assigns objects from `expression_list` to `target_list` on each iteration. Just as list assignment in a regular statement assigns values

```
>>> [x,y] = 100, 200
>>> x
100
>>> y
200
```

`for [k,v] in d.items()` assigns the tuple values iterated by `d.items()` to `x` and `y`. As a result, `{k*2:v/2 for (k,v) in d.items()}` and `{k*2:v/2 for [k,v] in d.items()}` are the same.

In your final case,

```
d3 = {k*2:v/2 for [k,v] in d.items() if [k,v] in d.items()}
```

The reason that `d3` is empty is that the `list` `[k,v]` is not in `d.items()`, which iterates tuples. But the `tuple` `k,v` is. Change the check and you get the full dictionary again

```
>>> d4 = {k*2:v/2 for [k,v] in d.items() if (k,v) in d.items()}
>>> d4
{2: 1.0, 6: 2.0, 10: 3.0}
```

A final word on assignment to a list, I was surprised that it is not a syntax error. In fact, when you do the assignment, you get a tuple not a list. I'm puzzled!

```
>>> z = [x,y] = (100,200)
>>> z
(100, 200)
```

Comment: @MayankMittal - yes, its just unpacking, I'm just personally surprised that it works with list syntax. Parens are used for grouping while square brackets are not. I always just assumed that the parens in `for (k,v) in d.items()` was just optional grouping.

Answer (score 1):

the `in` as a boolean operator return `False` at each iteration for `d3` because tuples and array are always different :

```
print(("foo") == ["foo"]) # False
print(("foo") == ("foo")) # True
print(["foo"] in [("foo")]) # False
print(["foo"] in [["foo"]]) # True
```

When using `in` as an iterator, it will output tuples of key-value, when typing `[k,v] in ...`  each iteration will unpack key and value into u,v, but `d.items()` is an array of tuple and comparing its element with array will always return `False`

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, the: `for (k,v) in d.items()` is the same as: `for [k,v] in d.items()` in dict comprehensions.

You might be interested to know that this code:

```
d4 = {k*2:v/2 for [k,v] in d.items() if (k,v) in d.items()}
print(d4)
```

produces the output:

```
{2: 1.0, 6: 2.0, 10: 3.0}
```

because it is `True` that `(k,v) in d.items()`

The difference is that `[k,v]` which is a list of two elements is *never* in `d.items()` which always returns a view with elements which are only ever `tuple`s, of which `(k,v)` is an example.